# Ionic 3 CORS issue in iPhone Simulator

Tags: cors, cordova-plugins, ionic3

I am getting what I believe to be a CORS issue in the iPhone Simulator version  SimulatorApp-829.6 / xCode 9.0

I built an ionic3 app w/ Cordova and can run it in the browser using a proxy.  But when I ran it in the sim or on my phone, it will not authenticate against the remote http call.

So I added Cordova debugger and debugged to the xCode console:

**This is the http error object:**

> {"_body":{"isTrusted":true},"status":0,"ok":false,"statusText":"","headers":{},"type":3,"url":null}

**This is the code I'm executing in the Ionic app (works in browser)**

```html
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    headers.append('Authorization', 'Basic ' + this.base64Service.encode(id + ':' + pw));
    headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    

    return this.http.get('http://myserver.com/api/v1/authenticate', {headers: headers}).map(res => res.json());
```

I'm really confused because 2 things:

1) I have the Cordova whitelist plugin installed and have had success before against the remote server.  Not sure what's going on

2) If I use Safari Developer > Simulator and connect to the app running in the simulator it gives this error:

```
Failed to load resource: Origin http://localhost:8080 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://myserver.com/api/v1/authenticate. Origin http://localhost:8080 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

How can you get a CORS issue in the Sim or actual device?  I think the resources were all file:// based.  Also, why wouldn't the Cordova whitelist plugin take care of the issue?

Thanks in advance.  Have spent many hours on this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I recently encountered a similar problem. My ionic app had been running with no issues for months, and I suddenly started to receive CORS errors on iOS.

The problem was that I switched to using `WKWebView` from `UIWebview`.

[This blog post](http://blog.ionic.io/wkwebview-for-all-a-new-webview-for-ionic/) explains more about `WKWebView` and why it is much better than its predecessor.

It also mentions this concerning CORS:

> UIWebview, or the older webview in iOS, never actually enforced CORS, but WKWebView does and does not provide a way to disable it. To address this, you need to implement CORS correctly and add the following entry:
>
> Origin: http://localhost:8080
>
> IF this is not possible (you do not own the API), a workaround can be to use the native HTTP plugin, @ionic-native/http.

So the two solutions are:

1. If you own the api you are using, enable CORS on it
2. If you can't modify the api, you can use [Ionic Native Http](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/http/)

I went with the first one and everything started working correctly again.

Comment: Could you tell me .
what is effort to make it with "if you can't modify the api, you can use Ionic Native Http" 
mine is small app only with 8 pages.

Comment: Currently i am using
import {Http, Headers,RequestOptions} from '@angular/http';
what will be my change

Comment: @Shamil I haven't used Ionic in a while, so I can't help much, but I would recommend following the instructions in the [Ionic Native HTTP docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/http) under "installation" and "usage".

Comment: Thanks a lot.  My server side team is ready to implement the Cors. Will it be easy compared to implement the native http